# log4j 2 - logger.entry(p1,p2,p3) with parameter names

Tags: java, log4j

Is there an easy way to use logger.entry(p1,p2,p3) from log4j 2 with the parameter names included in the output?

```
logger.entry(p1,p2,p3)
```

Result:

```
... entry params(val1, val2, val3)
```

But shut result in:

```
... entry params(p1=val1, p2=val2, p3=val3)
```

Edit:

The problem with a simple solution like

```
logger.info(p1+" "+p2+" "+p3);
```

or

```
logger.entry("p1="+p1,"p2="+p2,"p3="+p3)
```

is that the string is build before every function call and results in a performance lose. I ask me, if there is a build in way in log4j.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
logger.entry("p1="+p1,"p2="+p2,"p3="+p3)
```